# "calendar_date_select" plugin, How to change color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If anyone has used [calendar_date_select plugin](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/), could you please tell me how to customize the color of the calendar, based on it's [sample](http://2007.electronicholas.com/calendar), its color is red, how to set it to use other colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the docs show that you are asked to put the following helper in your template:

```
<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>
```

this tag can take options, so you can use it to specify which css file gets used like so:

```
<%= calendar_date_select_includes :style => 'green' %>
```

The different styles available to you should be in your `public/stylesheets/calendar_date_select` directory.

Comment: If I specified <%= calendar_date_select_includes :style => 'green' %>, do I still have to have the directory public/stylesheets/calendar_date_select directory??

Comment: yes, thats just a helper that links to the css file, it expects it to be in the public/stylesheets/calendar_date_select directory.  the following might help you with setting it up correctly: http://technicaldebt.wetpaint.com/page/Calendar+Date+Select

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a class to your helper:

```
<%= calendar_date_select_includes :class => 'calendar_select' %>
```

And then add to CSS file (normally in public/stylesheets folder) something like

```
.calendar_select {
    background-color: green
}
```